# C++ macros get an unexpected result？

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#define _VA_ARG_LIST2(t, a) t a
#define _VA_ARG_LIST4(t, a, b, c) \
  _VA_ARG_LIST2(t, a), _VA_ARG_LIST2(b, c)

int main() {

    cout << _VA_ARG_LIST4("A", "a", "B", "b"); // 输出 Aa
    return 0;
}
```

I want to get result is `"A a","B b"`,but I only have the `"Aa"`,I don't know what's wrong

I wonder why the result is `"Aa"`

Comment: It will expand into `"A" "a", "B" "b"`. And now you are in the domain of the comma operator behavior...

Comment: Re “I want to get result is `"A a","B b"`”: Do you want to get output of `"A a","B b"` from the program or do you want to get source code of `"A a","B b"` (or equivalent) from the macro replacement?

Comment: In C++ stop using macros like this. Learn about template functions and things like std::format Like this : https://onlinegdb.com/QO2ojXcqx (online demo)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_VA_ARG_LIST2`, `_VA_ARG_LIST4`) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: `#define _VA_ARG_LIST4(t, a, b, c) _VA_ARG_LIST2(_VA_ARG_LIST2(t, a), _VA_ARG_LIST2(b, c))` might be a little more like what you're after.

Comment: Macros are fun:  `_VA_ARG_LIST2('F', 3.14159)`.  Prefer inline functions or templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjacent string literals separated by whitespace are joined together by the compiler. So: `"A" "a"` becomes `"Aa"`, `"B" "b"` becomes `"Bb"`, etc.

Since you want the result of `_VA_ARG_LIST2()` to be separated by a space character, you will have to introduce an extra string literal into the concatenation, eg:

```
#define _VA_ARG_LIST2(t, a) t " " a
```

That way, `_VA_ARG_LIST2("A", "a")` will expand into `"A" " " "a"` and thus join into `"A a"`, `_VA_ARG_LIST2("B", "b")` will expand into `"B" " " "b"` and thus `"B b"`, etc.

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/cUQFrS)

Now, that being said, the expression `cout << _VA_ARG_LIST4("A", "a", "B", "b")` will expand into `cout << "A a", "B a"` which will display only `"A a"` because of how the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) works:

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its result is discarded (although if it has class type, it won't be destroyed until the end of the containing full expression), and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression `E2` begins

This will get interpreted by the compiler as two separate expressions:

`cout << "A a"`
and
`"B a"`, which is a no-op!

So, to output `"B b"` as well, you will have to replace the unescaped `,` in `_VA_ARG_LIST4()` with something else, either `","` or `<<`, etc.

For example:

```
#define _VA_ARG_LIST4(t, a, b, c) \
  _VA_ARG_LIST2(t, a) ", " _VA_ARG_LIST2(b, c)
```

will expand `cout << _VA_ARG_LIST4("A", "a", "B", "b")` into `cout << "A a, B b"`

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/GZ9ZRI)

Or:

```
#define _VA_ARG_LIST4(t, a, b, c) \
  _VA_ARG_LIST2(t, a) << _VA_ARG_LIST2(b, c)
```

will expand `cout << _VA_ARG_LIST4("A", "a", "B", "b")` into `cout << "A a" << "B b"`

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/TVlDBk)

Comment: Also, worth reminding that [identifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) that begin with an underscore are reserved. Using those leads to the program being ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: @heapunderrun not all underscored identifiers are reserved. Per the link you posted, the actual rules are a bit more restrictive: "*Identifiers that appear as appearing as a token or preprocessing token (i.e., not in `user-defined-string-literal` like `operator ""id`) of one of the following forms are reserved: 1) identifiers with a double underscore anywhere; 2) **identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter**; 3) in the global namespace, identifiers that begin with an underscore.*" In this case, the OP's code falls under the 2nd rule.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to briefly quote the 3rd rule ("_in the global namespace, identifiers that begin with an underscore_"). But you are right, because preprocessor macros have [their own scoping rules](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.scope), and the preprocessor knows nothing about namespaces, global or not, of course.

Comment: @heapunderrun right, preprocessor macros are processed before the compiling stage, so they don't exist in the global namespace.